# Communication problem inEC2 (Spring boot) and RDS (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a RDS instance (MySQL) and EC2 instance (Spring boot).

**Locally, my Spring Boot app correctly establishes the connection to my database in RDS.**

But when I install my Spring Boot app in EC2, the application tries to make the connection to the database in RDS (MySQL). But it throws this error at me:

`SQLCODE: 0 SQLSTATE: 08S01 TRACE: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`
`The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

In EC2, I have this security group inbound[image]

And outbound [image]

Comment: You jeed to check the underlying error message, such as access denied. Otherwise, we will not be able to help.

Comment: What security group does your RDS have?

Comment: @Hasho, I would think along the lines if I've changed some config on the local machine during initial steps for jdbc connectivity to RDBC and check to apply the same on EC2. Sometimes we might miss a small step as such. Or, try checking if the app connects to RDS from another local machine(new).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sound weird; because if something is working from your local laptop which is on public IP address; it should work from within AWS environment too. Anyway, for connection; you need to not check security group of EC2 only but also of RDS because RDS should allow incoming from EC2 also. Though exception doesn't look like connection/security group problem.

I feel it has something to do with your application.

Comment: Yeah, it was the RDS incoming connection.
RDS accepted only incoming MySQL (3306) connections, and I better changed it to accepting all connections (All trafic).